# Eclipse Indigo CDT: Function could not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

This feels silly, but its been 2 days...somewhere after upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 to 10.11 and from Eclipse Helios to Eclipse Indigo, I got stuck with the following problem:

## Problem Description:

I'm trying to use a function in math.h called isinf(), but the problem also occurs with things like isnan().
 The program compiles fine on the command line using make and fine in eclipse using build.
  But if I open the program file in eclipse it reports that it cannot reolve the isinf() function call.
  If I just insert the program contents into a new project and new source file, the error appears immediately.
  This problem did not occur under 11.04 with Eclipse Helios CDT

### Questions:

Why are these errors only reported when the program file is opened and not on when the program is compiled; why are the errors not detected make is run from the command line?
 Is there a solution/workaround available?

### Version Info

Linux Ubuntu 10.11 64-bit
 
Eclipse CDT Indigo, Service Release 1, Build id: 20110916-0149
 
(Also using Eclipse EE Indigo – if that makes a difference)
 
GNU Make 3.81
 
gcc 4.6.1-9Ubuntu3

### To Duplicate:

Please find the two files you'll need to replicate below:

**Step 0.** Verify that everything is fine outside of Eclipse
 
Copy the attached source file and make file
 
create a directory e.g. Mkdir FunTest
 
Save the source file a 'Test.cpp' and the makefile as 'makefile'
 
Open a command prompt and navigate to the directory e.g. FunTest
 
Enter 'make' 
 
Enter ./TestOut 
Program responds “is not infinite”

**Step 1.** Create the project in Eclipse
 
Open Eclipse
Select File|New|MakeFile Project with Existing Code
 
Click Browse – navigate to the directory (FunTest) and click ok
 
Select 'Linux GCC' from the Toolchain selector
 
Click Finish

**Step 2.** Find the Error
 
Click Build All (Ctrl-B) – project builds without errors
 
Open the project in the project explorer to display the file in the directory
 
Double click on the file “Test.cpp”
 
Note the error icon next to line testing for infinity
 
Note the 2 error messages:

```
Semantic error: Function _isinff could not be resolved 
Semantic error: Function _isinfl could not be resolved
```

**Test.cpp:**

```
include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int TestNum = 10;

if (isinf(TestNum) == 0)
    printf("Not infinite\n");


return 0;

}
```

makefile:

```
# Specify the compiler
CC = g++

# Specify the compiler flags
CFLAGS += -c

# Specify the files making up the application
SOURCES = Test.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = TestOut

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

install:
    @echo "Build complete!"
```

Answer (score 7):

I have experienced similar problems of the CDT reporting errors even though the code compiled fine within Eclipse Indigo.

> Project > Properties > Settings > Binary Parsers > "GNU Elf Parser"

helped in my case. I had the "Elf Parser" checked.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a problem that many others have had with eclipse CDT before. Sometimes shutting eclipse down and then starting it back up again is enough to help. If that isn't the case, take a look at what I have below:

[Compilation ok, but eclipse content assist having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148235/eclipse-cdt-shows-semantic-errors-but-compilation-is-ok)

Comment: I can only agree with that. A restart did indeed fix the problem. I didn't have this kind of problem in the previous version of Eclipse though.

Answer (score 4):

Check your includes: if you're using `include<math.h>` change it to `include<cmath>`. The same for `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`, you should replace by `cstdio` and `cstdlib`. Another option may be change you project to a C project instead of a C++.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing -lm option in your build preferences.
Project->Properties->Settings->Miscleanous->Other (linker) flags[]

Comment: With the errors happening, I made this change then did a clean/build.  Still had the errors.  Did a restart of Eclipse.  Errors gone.  Guess I have to wait a while to see if it comes back.

Comment: Re.  my previous note: It came back.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was solved by adding a specific ‘**Source Location**’ folder, and removing the default. In Luna, it is under:

> Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Source
>   Location