# Setup Eclipse for GTK-4.0

Tags: c, gtk, eclipse-cdt

**Intro**

I'm getting started with GTK. I chose Eclipse as IDE. Right now I am at the first page of the GTK tutorial (https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html).

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//#include <gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h>
//#include "/usr/lib/libLLVM-15.so"

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
...
```

I compiled with

```
gcc $( pkg-config --cflags gtk4 ) -o example-0 example-0.c $( pkg-config --libs gtk4 )
```

and it compiles and executes.

**Problem**

My problem is that Eclipse can't resolve `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` and the GTK syntax. I found some (mostly old) Questions that targeting this (I've read about to include `pkg-config --libs gtk4 --cflags gtk4` to the project path - I don't know how to do that) but I was not able to solve my problem.

**I've tried**

[Solution provided by BobMorane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910311/configured-eclipse-for-gtkmm-and-gtk-on-ubuntu/62203484#62203484)

adding $(pkg-config --libs gtk4 --cflags gtk4) to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ build Command line pattern

adding $$(pkg-config --libs gtk4 --cflags gtk4) to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ build Command line pattern

adding

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-4.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/sysprof-4 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/graphene-1.0 -I/usr/lib/graphene-1.0/include -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -pthread -lgtk-4 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgraphene-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ build Command line pattern.

**The last 3** did not change the compiler command which was:

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0  -MMD -MP -MF"example-0.d" -MT"example-0.o" -o "example-0.o" "../example-0.c"
```

Installing PKG-config support for Eclipse CDT 1.0.0

Replacing #include <gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h> with #include <gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h> which resulted with this error:

```
/usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h:30:10: fatal error: gtk/css/gtkcss.h: No such file or directory
```

Nothing that I've tried worked.
**What I want to achieve**

Syntax highlighting and compiling from the IDE.
How to do this in Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27.0)?

**What worked for me**

1. Creating a empty Meson project
2. example-0.c from the tutorial page
3. Creating meson.build file

my meson.build:

```
project('monitorUpdater', 'c') 
dependencies = [ 
  # dependency('gtk+-3.0'), 
  dependency('gtk4'), 
  dependency('openssl'), 
  dependency('X11')
]

sources = [
    'example-0.c'
]

executable('gtkTest', sources, dependencies : dependencies)
```

IntelliSense, building and running works.

Comment: I already answered a similar question for Gtkmm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203484/6575139). Not exactly your case, but I think it could help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Tried it but unfortunately it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pkg-config support has some strange things. I switched to a meson build. Eclipse can generate a meson project. My meson build file in project root:

```
project('monitorUpdater', 'c')
dependencies = [ dependency('gtk4'), dependency('openssl'), dependency('X11')]
incdir = include_directories('src/include')
subdir('src')
executable('monitorUpdater', sources, dependencies : dependencies,  include_directories : incdir )
```

My sources are in the src folder. This folder also contains a meson.build file:

```
sources = files('main.c', 'screen.c', 'udp.c','updateThread.c','timer.c' ,'settings.c')
```

Answer (score 0):

For using eclipse managed make:  Quick (and dirty I suppose)
In terminal:

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk4
```

Copy result text with all the `-I..` items in Project properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC compiler->Miscellaneous->Other flags field.

```
pkg-config --libs gtk4
```

Append result to Expert settings -command line pattern in Project properties->C/C++ Build->Settings-> GCC linker.

Also add /usr/include/gtk-4.0 to C/C++ General Paths and Symbols so the editor can also find gtk headers.

After this exercise I noticed a great plugin for eclipse: Pkg-config support, to be installed from the marketplace. Just set a checkbox.....

Comment: I've tried to follow the steps. I don't have this "Project properties-> GCC compiler->Miscellaneous->Other flags field."  in my installation. I can't find "Expert settings -command line pattern in Project properties-> GCC linker" either.
I have "/usr/include/gtk-4.0" in my project include folder visible (gtk-3.0 and 2.0 too). I don't have "Project properties", i have "Prpoperties", I have "C/C++ build" instead of "GCC compiler"· The rest of menu seems to have a totally different structure. Which build plugin are you using? I have C/C++ as it comes from the Eclipse C++ installation

Comment: Clarified eclipse menu. The items ar for a managed make project.

Comment: Tried it with the Makefile build. My expert settings command is    ${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} ${EXTRA_FLAGS} $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)   . I also tried to put the output of the command. The build keeps failing, the GTK classes can not be resolved.

Comment: The Pkg-config support has some strange things,,  I switched to a meson build. Eclipse can generate a meson project. My meson build file in project root: project('monitorUpdater', 'c')

dependencies = [
#  dependency('gtk+-3.0'),
  dependency('gtk4'),
  dependency('openssl'),
  dependency('X11')
'code'
incdir = include_directories('src/include')
subdir('src')
executable('IntercomUpdater', sources, dependencies : dependencies,  include_directories : incdir )

Comment: it finally worked with a meson project. thanks a lot. building, running and syntax highlighting works now. I thought this was not going to happen anymore. thanks a lot