# Eclipse indexer proper c++11 syntax highlighting when generating projects with cmake

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I know you can enable proper syntax highlighting with the GXX_EXPERIMENTAL hack described here:
[Eclipse CDT indexer does not know C++11 containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17131744/eclipse-cdt-indexer-does-not-know-c11-containers/17135819#17135819)

But i think, when generating projects with cmake, one should never need to touch the project settings at all.

So. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple.

The eclipse cdt generator ignores the definitions added with add_definitions(...) when parsing the symbols. Instead it uses the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1.
So all you have to do is: Add -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1=-std=c++11 when invoking cmake

Generating project files from commandline:

```
cmake ../../src -G"Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.2 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1=-std=c++11
```

Generating projects from cmake gui:

```
- Select source and build directory.
- now BEFORE hitting configure or generate. Press "Add Entry" and add a new entry. Name:CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1 Type:STRING Value:-std=c++11
- press Generate and create the Eclipse project
```

It is important to set the CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ARG1 upfront before hitting configure or generate the first time!

That´s it. The project will be generated with correct symbols. indexer, syntax highlighting and autocompletion should work as intended without changing any project settings by hand.

Comment: It did not worked for me. I'm using cmake  3.5.1 and eclipse Kepler.I still had to do what the second point here suggest to do (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381512/1971003) - Anything I'm missing here ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned, the invocation of the project generators runs **before** the parsing of the `CMakeLists.txt`.
Thus, any definitions inside of `CMakeLists.txt` don't have any effect on the generated project files.

In case of eclipse-project generation, the capabilities of the compiler are requested inside [CMakeExtraGeneratorDetermineCompilerMacrosAndIncludeDirs.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.8.0-rc1/Modules/CMakeExtraGeneratorDetermineCompilerMacrosAndIncludeDirs.cmake).
In line [23](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.8.0-rc1/Modules/CMakeExtraGeneratorDetermineCompilerMacrosAndIncludeDirs.cmake#L23) the variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is parsed which is evaluated in line [30](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.8.0-rc1/Modules/CMakeExtraGeneratorDetermineCompilerMacrosAndIncludeDirs.cmake#L30).
Especially **this** `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable can only be set while invoking `cmake` from command line.

**Recommodation of proper cmake invokation**: `cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11"` (or replace `c++11` with eg. `c++14` or any other standard you like)

**Hint:**
The result from evaluating line [30](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.8.0-rc1/Modules/CMakeExtraGeneratorDetermineCompilerMacrosAndIncludeDirs.cmake#L30) can be seen from running the following command as an example: `touch /tmp/dummy; /usr/bin/c++ -v -E -x c++ -std=c++11 -dD /tmp/dummy`. It outputs all the defines from the compiler which are parsed into the eclipse-project:

```
...
#define __STDC__ 1
#define __cplusplus 201103L
...
```

Comment: This worked for me, using Eclipse 4.5, cmake 3.7.2 and TDM-GCC 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

In version 3.1 of cmake a new variable CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD was introduced that can activate C++11 support. Try something like this:

```
cmake ../../src -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11
```

This seems to carry through to the generated Eclipse project. I tried it with verison 3.2.0-rc2 and Eclipse recognized C++11 features like std::shared_ptr<>.

Some documentation links:

- [CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html?highlight=cmake_cxx_standard)
- [Optional Compile Features](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html#optional-compile-features) (read towards the bottom of the section)

Comment: Nope, I've tried setting CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14 with CMake 3.2.1. GCC sets standard to gnu++14, and Eclipse doesn't.

Comment: Try `cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++14" .`