# Set CMake generated Eclipse project to recognize C++11 features like std::to_string()

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

Using Eclipse 3.8.1, I've generated a C++ project using CMake with two subprojects.

Both subprojects specify

```
# Use C++11 to compile your pass (i.e., supply -std=c++11).
target_compile_features(OpaquePass PRIVATE cxx_range_for cxx_auto_type)
```

in their CMakeLists.txt.

Now, this doesn't seem to work, since Eclipse cannot recognize methods like `std::to_string()`.

I've tried to configure Eclipse myself, but right-clicking on project properties, I get these options:

[image]

It doesn't seem that I can specify any flags to GCC or customize behavior. What can I do to make Eclipse function properly with C++11?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/9131763/25507 address your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse indexer proper c++11 syntax highlighting when generating projects with cmake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358389/eclipse-indexer-proper-c11-syntax-highlighting-when-generating-projects-with-c)