# Function to_string() was not resolved using g++ mingw--w64 5.3.0

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

In Eclipse I am using mingw-w64 V5.3.0 as the compiler and I have enabled C++11 (which was the solution in the following related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381137/eclipse-function-to-string-could-not-be-resolved) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074724/c11-full-support-on-eclipse)).  My compilation command looks as follows (from eclipse console window):

g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\Launch.o" "..\src\Launch.cpp"

The simple code I am attempting to run is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string test = std::to_string(0);
    std::cout <<"HI" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles but for an error stated in the question.  Running it without the `to_string` line works fine.  There have been suggestions back in 2012 that MingW has a problem with to_string(), but was resolved in later versions has shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g).

Screen shot below:

[image]

And the console output is as follows:

[image]

The following is the error I receive when running the code from the .exe directly:

[image]

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is a linking issue, however it is linking correctly to `iostream` which is in the same directory as `string`.

Comment: It compiles fine, but with an error? Can you show us the actual error?

Comment: Yes, it compiles fine but for an error I meant, which I've now corrected in the text.  I will show a screen shot

Comment: The error from the output console (as text) would be best.

Comment: Ah, there isn't one.  The console shows no errors, screen shot attached in a mo

Comment: Try rebuilding the index.

Comment: Is it a equivalent of intellisense error (visual studio), I mean an error from IDE, but not from real compilation ?

Comment: I thought this too yes, but when the program is executed it doesn't display the "HI" statement which suggests its crashing before that is run

Comment: Are you executing it directly from eclipse? Then you might need to select the correct console first.

Comment: Strange that you use 2 standards, C++0x **and** C++11.

Comment: Oh good grief, that isn't correct indeed, well spotted there.

Comment: I have corrected the flag, it now only uses C++11, though unfortunately the problem remains... however - thanks to Aconcagua having rebuilt the index the error does disapear.  But the program still crashes.  I have included the screen shot of the crash when running the .exe directly.

Comment: It is not a crash, but a linking issue. It seems that you don't find the standard lib... Recheck your compiler installation and settings.

Comment: So it would seem, strange though that it finds the <iostream> library fine, both are in the same folder.  I might post a separate question on this.

Comment: My guess is your `mingw/bin` directory is not on your PATH, so it can't find `libstdc++6.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse was looking in **System32** for the library and driver files, despite PATH and Eclipse pointing to the MingW64 compiler on the computer.  Eclipse is also showing it is linked to the MingW64 libraries correctly as the path to the headers when right-clicking and opening deceleration is shown to be correct.  Why then it looks in System32 for the library at run-time I don't understand.

The problem was 'solved' by copying the entire MingW64 compiler driver folder into the System32 folder on Windows.

Comment: Yikes! I'd check if eclipse is configured to override some environment variables in the project properties.
An alternative would be to link libstdc++ statically, if you really can't fix your environment.