# Error messages in Eclipse CDT on Ubuntu in (Compiling & Running!) C++11 project

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, c++11

I'm having trouble with Eclipse CDT. When trying to write a program with C++11 code in it,
I'm getting error messages that the C++11 functions "cannot be resolved", despite the program compiling and running perfectly fine.
I've searched for solutions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966976/eclipse-indigo-cdt-function-could-not-be-resolved) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148235/eclipse-cdt-shows-semantic-errors-but-compilation-is-ok)), but none of them is working for me.

This is a small example:
[image]

I have gcc / g++ 4.7.3 installed and set the `std=c++11` flag in the project settings (C/C++ Build --> Settings --> Tool Settings --> GCC C++ Compiler --> Miscellaneous)

Also, if I insert the `__cplusplus`macro somewhere, it's giving me the correct value `201103`.

Any idea why this happens only for C++11 specific features?

Comment: did u do `std=c++11` or `-std=c++11`? also are your lib paths defined properly?

Comment: -std=c++11 of course, sorry. What do you mean by defining the lib paths?

Comment: [Eclipse Doc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_proj_paths.htm) Basically that u need to specify where your C++ libarys are

Comment: I do have the C++ include libraries specified (like `/usr/include/c++/4.7`, etc.), otherwise the project wouldn't compile and run i guess. Anyway, there are no libraries specified. Are they necessary for this simple project? Where can I find the C++11 specific libraries?